# 64Bit Applications installed with QGIS/osgeo4w

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo4w, 64bit

Is python 64bit and gdal 64bit automatically installed when QGIS 64bit is installed via osgeo4w 64bit?

I currently have a custom 64bit python and gdal setup on my pc. However, this setup causes some issues whenever I want to import OTB, grass or qgis libraries into a py script.

Comment: yes but it is packaged inside the OSgeo4W path (check PYTHONHOME env in OSGeo4W shell) => different by your installed python. This is because python is not installed by default on Win and in this way no administration permission are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is, but it is packaged inside the OSgeo4W path (check PYTHONHOME env in OSGeo4W shell) => different by your installed python. This is because python is not installed by default on Win and in this way no administration permission are required.